# What should I do? I have a recursive function that returns the mth item of a n-bonacci sequence. It has for loop. I am banned from using loops

Tags: python

I have the following recursive function to get the mth term of a n-bonacci sequence as shown below this question. My problem is that the use of for and while loops is totally banned from the code, so I need to get rid off

```
for i in range(1, n+1): 
    temp += n_bonacci(n,m-i)
```

and convert the code into something that is not a loop but nevertheless achieves the same effect. Among the things I can use, but this is not an exclusive enumeration, is: (1) use built-in functions like `sum()` and `.join()` and (2) use list comprehensions.

The full code is as follows:

```
def n_bonacci(n,m):  #n is the number of n initial terms; m is the mth term.
    if (m < n-1):
        return 0
    elif (m == n-1):
        return 1
    else:
        temp = 0
        #[temp += n_bonacci(n,m-i) for i in range(n)] #this is an attempt at using list comprehension
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            temp += n_bonacci(n,m-i)
        return temp

print("n_bonacci:",n_bonacci(2,10))
print("n_bonacci:",n_bonacci(7,20))
```

Comment: List comprehensions *are* loops. Just compact special-purpose ones.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Among the things I can use... list comprehensions" Okay; so do you know how to write a list comprehension at all? Did you try to replace the loop with a list comprehension? What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code as follows using list comprehensions:

```py
def n_bonacci(n,m):  #n is the number of n initial terms; m is the mth term.
    if (m < n-1):
        return 0
    elif (m == n-1):
        return 1
    else:
        return sum(n_bonacci(n, m-i) for i in range(1, n + 1))

print("n_bonacci:",n_bonacci(2,10))
print("n_bonacci:",n_bonacci(7,20))
```

To go beyond @Grismar 's answer you can write your own version of sum which doesn't use loops.

```py
def n_bonacci_loopless(n, m):
    def recsum(l, s=0):
        return recsum(l[1:], s + l[0])

    def inner(i, c):
        if i == m:
            return recsum(c)
        else:
            return inner(i+1, c[-(n-1):] + [recsum(c)])

    if m < n-1:
        return 0
    elif (m == n-1):
        return 1
    else:
        return inner(n, [0] * (n-1) + [1])
```

Comment: sum(n_bonacci(n, m-**i**) for i in range(1, n + 1))

Comment: @ArifaChan should have used clipboard :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that avoids any type of loop, including loops hidden inside comprehensions:

```
def n_bonacci_loopless(n, m):
    def inner(i, c):
        if i == m:
            return sum(c)
        else:
            return inner(i+1, c[-(n-1):] + [sum(c)])

    if m < n-1:
        return 0
    elif (m == n-1):
        return 1
    else:
        return inner(n, [0] * (n-1) + [1])
```

The base cases are the same, but for recursive cases it initialises a list of collected results `c` with `n-1` zeroes, followed by a one, the sum of which would be the correct answer for `m == n`.

For `m > n`, the inner function is called again as long as `i < m`, summing the list and appending the result to the end of the last `n-1` elements of the list so far.

If you are allowed to use comprehensions, the answer is trivial:

```
def n_bonacci(n,m):
    if (m < n-1):
        return 0
    elif (m == n-1):
        return 1
    else:
        return sum(n_bonacci(n, m-i) for i in range(1, n+1))
```